# CSS absolute position inside a scrollable div in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a div which is scrollable with absolute positioned children inside. I want the absolute positioned elements to be visible even when the parent is scrolled. I know I need to set the parent element to position: relative to achieve this, but I'm using Bootstrap 4, and if I set the parent to relative, nothing changes.

[Here you can see the starting state, when the parent is scrollable.](https://jsfiddle.net/3adctabu/2/)
Note the **lines-scrollable** class:

```
<div id="opened" class="col-12 align-self-start lines lines-scrollable">
```

[Here you can see the state when the overlay and the popup (absolute positioned children) are displayed.](https://jsfiddle.net/3adctabu/3/) Note the **lines-non-scrollable** class on their parent:

```
<div id="opened" class="col-12 align-self-start lines lines-non-scrollable">
```

Everything is fine at this point because the scrolling position is 0:

```
$('#opened').scrollTop(0);
```

[But if you scroll, the absolute positioned children are moving with the scrolled content out of the visible area too.](https://jsfiddle.net/3adctabu/4/) You can emulate the scrolling with:

```
$('#opened').scrollTop(100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set something as absolute you put it in a location relative to the container (nearest container with position absolute or relative...). But when you scroll down the 0 position goes up thats why you are seeing this behavior.

In other words, when you scroll the div up, the relative location 0 changes as well so the inner absolute div will also scroll up.

You have two options:

1. List item set the position to fixed, however that makes it relative to the page (so fixed with position top: 0; will ALWAYS be at the top of the page regardless of where it is in the html

OR

2. Move the inner absolute div one level up and make the container relative so your HTML would look something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/3adctabu/6/ - working example of the jsfiddle you provided for the 2nd optin.

```
<div class="outer-container-that-is-relative">
  <div class="inner-absolute"></div>
  <div class="scrollable-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I just had move out the overlay also, and edit the height of both absolute elements, and it is OK now.